# Error en el manejo de nav menu en visual studio 2015 web forms con c#

Tags: html

estoy desarrollando un sitio web, le he puesto en un menú utilizando nav con un par de submenús, cuando ejecuto el programa ingresa en la primera opción de menú de forma correcta, pero al accezar un segunda opción me da el siguiente error:

Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.

No se encuentra el recurso.
en el href le doy la siguiente url "Mantenimientos/pagina.aspx", cuando da el error le agrega otro "Mantenimientos" lo deja de la siguiente forma "Mantenimientos/Mantenimientos/pagina.aspx", Mantenimientos es una carpeta dentro del proyecto donde se alojan varias páginas.

Este es el código que uso:

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="Default.aspx">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="Acercade.aspx">Acerca de</a></li>
  <li><a href="Contacto.aspx">Contacto</a></li>
  <li><a>Movimientos</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Movimientos/Pagina1.aspx">Proceso1</a></li>
        <li><a href="Movimientos/Pagina2.aspx">Proceso2</a></li>
        <li><a href="Movimientos/Pagina3.aspx">Proceso3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Mantenimientos</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Mantenimientos/Proceso4.aspx">Proceso4</a></li>
        <li><a href="Mantenimientos/Proceso5.aspx">Proceso5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hola Rodolfo bienvenido a [es.so], sería mucho mejor si compartes el código en texto en ves de en imagen. Te invito a leer el [tour] y [ask]. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te fijas en los enlaces en Mantenimientos no tienes Pagina sino Proceso, seguramente ese sea el error. Tu código tendría que quedar así:

Los cambios son en los dos últimos enlaces, tu los tienes como proceso4.aspx y proceso5.aspx y yo los he puesto como pagina4.aspx y pagina5.aspx.

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="Default.aspx">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="Acercade.aspx">Acerca de</a></li>
  <li><a href="Contacto.aspx">Contacto</a></li>
  <li><a>Movimientos</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Movimientos/Pagina1.aspx">Proceso1</a></li>
        <li><a href="Movimientos/Pagina2.aspx">Proceso2</a></li>
        <li><a href="Movimientos/Pagina3.aspx">Proceso3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Mantenimientos</a>
    <ul>
        LOS CAMBIOS SON ESTOS DOS ENLACES:
        <li><a href="Mantenimientos/Pagina4.aspx">Proceso4</a></li>
        <li><a href="Mantenimientos/Pagina5.aspx">Proceso5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Para solucionar tu problema y sin ver el resto del código se me ocurren dos maneras de solucionarlo, si el menú lo copias y lo pegas en cada página puedes editar las rutas dependiendo de la página en la que estés, por ejemplo si estás en Movimientos/Pagina1.aspx la ruta para acceder a Acerca de tendría que ser ../Acercade.aspx, es decir, tienes que salir de la carpeta Movimientos y luego acceder al archivo, o para acceder a Pagina2.aspx la ruta tiene que ser Pagina2.aspx, sin añadir Movimientos porque ya estás en esa carpeta.

Pero si el menú no lo copias y pegas si no que lo tienes en un archivo aparte y lo llamas en cada página lo que puedes hacer es tener todos los archivos en la misma carpeta, por ejemplo borras las carpetas de Movimientos y Mantenimiento después de sacar sus archivos, de esta forma tendrás todos los archivos en el mismo nivel y no tendrás que editar la ruta dependiendo de donde estés, simplemente poniendo el nombre del archivo podrás acceder a él. Si eliges la segunda opción tu código debería quedar así:

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="Default.aspx">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="Acercade.aspx">Acerca de</a></li>
  <li><a href="Contacto.aspx">Contacto</a></li>
  <li><a>Movimientos</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Pagina1.aspx">Proceso1</a></li>
        <li><a href="Pagina2.aspx">Proceso2</a></li>
        <li><a href="Pagina3.aspx">Proceso3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Mantenimientos</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Pagina4.aspx">Proceso4</a></li>
        <li><a href="Pagina5.aspx">Proceso5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perdón no veo la diferencia, que linea es la que cambiaste?

Comment: He editado mi respuesta indicando específicamente donde he hecho el cambio, espero que te sirva para solucionar tu problema. Si el error continua coméntamelo para intentar ayudarte.

Comment: Ok, perdón ya los vi, si había un error ahí, pero el problema es que si ejecuto la página web, carga perfectamente la página "Default" o la de "Acercade", igual sucede con la de "Contacto", inclusive la "Pagina1" o las otras dos "Pagina2", "Pagina3", la primera vez para cualquiera de estas últimas 3, pero al intentar ingresar a otra de las páginas después de correr alguna de movimientos les agrega a la url "Movimientos", entonces después de cargar cualquiera de las tres páginas de movimientos, si acceso a defalut da un error dice que url: Movimientos/Defalult.aspx no existe

Comment: ¿En las páginas donde te llevan los enlaces también tienes ese mismo menú de navegación? Por ejemplo si entras a Movimientos/Pagina1.aspx ¿tienes el mismo menú con un enlace a Default.aspx?, si es así ese es el error, porque si estás dentro de la carpeta Movimientos y quieres acceder a Default tienes que subir un nivel de esta manera: ../Default.aspx o si quieres acceder a la Pagina2 solo tienes que poner Pagina2.aspx, sin añadir Movimientos porque ya estas dentro de esa carpeta. Si esto te funciona dímelo para editar mi respuesta y explicártelo mejor.

Comment: Así es el menú es parte de la página maestra, esta en todas las páginas, como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: He editado mi respuesta explicándotelo, espero que te sirva para solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Aiub, en esta solución hay que tener todas las páginas en un mismo directorio.